# Как сформировать документ в гугл документах на основе данных из форм?

Tags: google-docs

У меня есть форма:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данные из формы передаются в таблицу (можно подключить только одну таблицу):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос, теперь хочу реализовать чтобы данные из базы формировали справку (стандарт документ в гугл документах). Как сделать чтобы в поля ФИО и т.д заполнялись поля из формы или базы (таблицы где сохраняются данные).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Не претендую на полное решение поставленной задачи, так как не все её детали известны. Тем не менее, могу предложить общее направление для решения.

Надеюсь, подготовить в коде необходимые данные для подстановки в шаблон Вы сможете. Я рекомендую дополнительно снабдить используемый шаблон закладками (bookmarks) - в тех местах, где начинаются ключевые слова для подстановок. Например, непосредственно перед словом "ФИО_КЛИЕНТ".

После того, как закладки установлены, выполняем следующий код (функция fill):

```
function fill() {
  // Извлеките заранее данные с листа для подстановки значений
  var dictionary = {
    'ФИО_КЛИЕНТ': 'Тест Петрович',
    'NUMBER': 123
  };

  // Подставьте эти данные в шаблон
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var bs = doc.getBookmarks();
  for (var i in bs) {
    var pos = bs[i].getPosition();
    var templateText = bs[i].getPosition().getElement().asText().getText();
    var text = substitute(templateText, dictionary);
    if (text != undefined) bs[i].getPosition().getElement().asText().setText(text);
  }

  // Опционально: можно удалить использованные закладки после подстановки значений
  while (bs.length > 0) {
    bs.pop().remove();
  }
}

// Подстановка с использованием поиска подстроки
function substitute(templateText, dictionary) {
  for (var key in dictionary) {
    var index = templateText.indexOf(key);
    if (index > -1) return templateText.substring(0, index) + 
      dictionary[key] + templateText.substring(index + key.length);
  }
}
```